# change default values for force:inputfield lookup based on some filter

Tags: lightning, lookup

Force:inputfield displays the lookup values perfectly , but i need to filter the values based on  certain field , can i do that .

for example:

```
 <aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" default="{ sobjectType: 'Task' }" access="public"/>
     <force:inputField value="{!v.task.WhoId}"   />
</aura:component>
```

This displays the contact lookup perfectly , my requirement is on task and  Contact there is field called region if i select region as APAC , the autosuggest lookup should only show the contact related to the region APAC.